# What am I? You've definitely heard of me

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

I was used in 1812,

I am in the title of the fourth.

Flash!  Fuji is my competitor

And you may have seen me on websites that allow the user to talk about books.

I'm a rapper and you can shoot me.

Sorry if certain lines seem to be misleading.  Also, (***shocker!!***) no obscure book or movie references.  I'm not sure of the wordplay tag...  But we'll only know if it fits when you've solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> Cannon/Canon

I was used in 1812,

> Cannons were used in the war of 1812.

I am in the title of the fourth.

> Pachelbel's *Canon in D* (D is the fourth letter)

Flash! Fuji is my competitor

> Canon is a competitor of Fuji the camera manufacturer.

And you may have seen me on websites that allow the user to talk about books.

> The word "canon" refers to books that are accepted as legitimate by a community.

I'm a rapper and you can shoot me.

> [Canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_%28rapper%29) the rapper, and you could shoot him with a cannon.

Comment: I knew that! I just didn't answer soon enough...

Comment: Cannons are also a well-known part of the 1812 Overture.

Comment: Well... You shouldn't exactly shoot someone(even though that's what I meant).  Should I be worried that you came up with the right answer so fast?  And was it that easy?  (Snaps) aww man...

Comment: @AJL I thought Flash Fuji was a dead giveaway.

Comment: Yeah... I was kind of humming Canon and decided to write a riddle, as I can never think of a topic.

Comment: Funny, because I can't accept the answer for three minutes.  Arghh